# Unable To Insert MS Project Ribbon On Project Open

Tags: vba, project, ms-project

So following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee767705(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN I have looked to migrate my MSProject.OfficeUI file holding my custom icons to code to be run from This Project on open. This was due due to moving to a new service where the app data will not be accessable by a user & a want to keep the features available.

How ever although I have no errors on the code and even walked it via F8 the new ribbion is not created.

Can you see any thing that I need to adjust to make this work ?

Thanks

Terran

```
Private Sub Project_Activate(ByVal pj As Project)
    AddRibbon
End Sub

Private Sub AddRibbon()
            ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee767705(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
            Dim ribbonXml As String

            ribbonXml = "<mso:customUI xmlns:mso=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"">"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "  <mso:ribbon>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "    <mso:qat/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "    <mso:tabs>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "      <mso:tab id=""highlightTab"" label=""Highlight"" insertBeforeQ=""mso:TabFormat"">"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "        <mso:group id=""toolsGroup"" label=""Tools"" autoScale=""true"">"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""tools1"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""tools2"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""tools3"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""tools4"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""tools5"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""tools6"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "        </mso:group>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "        <mso:group id=""viewsGroup"" label=""Views"" autoScale=""true"">"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""views1"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""views2"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""views3"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""views4"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""views5"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""views6"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""views7"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""views8"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""views9"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""view10"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""views11"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""views12"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "        </mso:group>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "        <mso:group id=""reportingGroup"" label=""Reporting"" autoScale=""true"">"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""report1"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""report2"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""report3"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""report4"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""report5"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""report6"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "        </mso:group>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "        <mso:group id=""utilsGroup"" label=""Utilities"" autoScale=""true"">"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""util1"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""util2"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""util3"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""util4"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""util5"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""util6"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""util7"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""util8"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""util9"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""util10"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""util11"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""util12"" label=""Toggle Manual Task Color"" imageMso=""DiagramTargetInsertClassic"" onAction=""ToggleManualTasksColor""/>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "        </mso:group>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "      </mso:tab>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "    </mso:tabs>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "  </mso:ribbon>"
            ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "</mso:customUI>"

            ActiveProject.SetCustomUI (ribbonXml)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved after a PC reboot - odd.

T

EDIT - for any one else - note the use of "" with in the statment